# Problem sending hashtable in PowerShell data to API

Tags: powershell, vmware

I have a function which has the following parameters, my idea is replace NetworkMapping with a dynamic hashtable

```
New-XVCMRequest xxxxxxx    -NetworkMapping @{"Infra (Network)"="Infra (DistributedVirtualPortgroup);"Infra2 (Network)"="Infra2 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)";"Infra3 (Network)"="Infra3 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}
```

I've made a hashtable:

```
$vm2 = Get-VM -Name "xxx"
$networkDetails2 = $vm2 | Get-NetworkAdapter
$hash = $null
$hash = @{}
 foreach ($net in $networkDetails2) {

 $hash.add($net.Networkname + '(Network)',$net.Networkname + '(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)' )

}
```

The problem is when I run

```
New-XVCMRequest xxxxxxx     -NetworkMapping $hash
```

Send to the API web the hash with ":"  instead "=" and "," instead ";"

Sent bad example

```
Infra2(Network)":"Infra2(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)","Infra(Network)":"Infra(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}
```

How suppose to send the data

```
Infra2(Network)"="Infra2(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)";"Infra(Network)"="Infra(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}
```

Comment: Not sure on the data mapping, but colons and commas indicate that it is trying to send the data formatted as the industry standard for API communication as a JSON format. If you have specific data formatting requirements, you will have to format it and send it as RAW text.

Comment: As a test, what happens if you hard-code the value of the hashtable variable? E.g. ```$hash = @{"Infra (Network)"="Infra (DistributedVirtualPortgroup);"Infra2 (Network)"="Infra2 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)";"Infra3 (Network)"="Infra3 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}```. Also, where does New-XVCMRequest come from? Is it a function you’ve written? Can you post the code?

Comment: Ok, found the function - https://github.com/vmware/PowerCLI-Example-Scripts/blob/master/Modules/CrossvCentervmotion/XVM.psm1. I noticed you’ve got spaces in the original hashtable keys - e.g. ```Infra (Network)``` - but **not** in your  $hash variable - ```Infra(Network)```. Could **that** be the issue, rather than the ”:” vs “=“?

Comment: I think that was not the error , I think was a bad paste here in stack. But I will check it agan

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will check  it!